# OpenX only option?

Tags: api, ads, openx, advertisement-server

Is there any other alternative (commercial or not) to OpenX Source to build my own ad network in which my publishers suggest their sides and get their custom tags automatically?

Most of other adservers, like Adzerk or EPOM have just reporting API's if I am fine which would make impossible what I have in mind.

Comment: Curious why this would be impossible with Adzerk? You should be able to use our API to build anything you are looking to do - if not let us know.

Comment: Hi James! Sorry I am not a developer myself so I am not sure but I read a bit of your API and I expected to find something like "Get Publisher Tag" or something like this and I did not find anything. Could you tell me how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check with www.dreamajax.com and they have product with unique interfaces built on top of OpenX and many adnetworks and adservers at present use their platform. They have also extended it for Mobile, In-Game and Video.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at www.switchconcepts.com, contact david.lane@switchconcepts.com.  Switch supports many ad networks and publishers.  We can explore your precise requirements and see if we support these.  I suspect we already do.   We are a commercial adserver (with industry leading support) with integrated RTB and private exchange support.